# C++: is this a correct way to use integer variables as pointers to a function call?

Tags: c++

I am a C++ newbie.

Context: I found this third-party snippet of code that *seems* to work, but based on my (very limited) knowledge of C++ I *suspect* it will cause problems. The snippet is as follows:

```
int aVariable;

int anInt = 1;
int anotherInt = 2;
int lastInt = 3;

aVariable = CHAIN(anInt, anotherInt, lastInt);
```

Where CHAIN is defined as follows (this is part of a library):

```
int CHAIN(){ Map(&CHAIN, MakeProcInstance(&_CHAIN), MAP_IPTR_VPN); }
int _CHAIN(int i, int np, int p){ return ASMAlloc(np, p, &chainproc); }
int keyalloc[16384], kpos, alloc_locked, tmp[4];

int ASMAlloc(int np, int p, alias proc)
{
    int v, x;   
//  if(alloc_locked) return 0 & printf("WARNING: you can declare compound key statements (SEQ, CHAIN, EXEC, TEMPO, AXIS) only inside main() call, and not during an event.\xa");
    v = elements(&keyalloc) - kpos - 4;
    if(v < np | !np) return 0;                      // not enough allocation space or no parameters
    Map(&v, p); Dim(&v, np);                        // v = params array
    keyalloc[kpos] = np + 4;                        // size
    keyalloc[kpos+1] = &proc;                       // function
    keyalloc[kpos+2] = kpos + 2 + np;               // parameters index
    while(x < np)
    {
        keyalloc[kpos+3+x] = v[x];
        x = x+1;
    }
    keyalloc[kpos+3+np] = kpos + 3 | JUMP; 
    x = ASMFind(kpos);
    if(x == kpos) kpos = kpos + np + 4;
    return x + 1 | PROC;    // skip block size
}

int ASMFind(int x)
{
    int i, j, k; while(i < x)
    {
        k = i + keyalloc[i]; // next
        if(keyalloc[i] == keyalloc[x])  // size
            if(keyalloc[i+1] == keyalloc[x+1]) // proc
            {
                j = x-i;
                i = i+3;
                while(keyalloc[i] == keyalloc[j+i]) i = i+1;    // param
                if((keyalloc[i] & 0xffff0000) == JUMP) return x-j;
            }
        i = k; 
    }
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT**:

The weird thing is that running

```
CHAIN(aVariable);
```

effectively executes

```
CHAIN(anInt, anotherInt, lastInt);
```

Somehow. This is what led me to believe that *aVariable* is, in fact, a pointer.

**QUESTION:**

Is it correct to store a parametrized function call into an integer variable like so? Does "aVariable" work just as a pointer, or is this likely to corrupt random memory areas?

Comment: You're storing a return value.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Apologies, I missed a crucial part of the problem. Running

    CHAIN(aVariable);

effectively executes

    CHAIN(anInt, anotherInt, lastInt);

Somehow. This is what led me to believe that aVariable is, in fact, a pointer. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a function (through an obfuscated interface), and storing the result in an integer. It might or might not cause problems, depending on how you use the value / what you expect it to mean.

Your example contains too many undefined symbols for the reader to provide any better answer.

Also, I think this is C, not C++ code.